# Can't customize xah-fly-keys

Tags: key-bindings, package, keymap, keyboard-layout

I've read the documentation about customizing but I think my knowledge of Lisp is limiting things a bit. I want to bind `a` in command mode to `move-beginning-of-line` and QWERTY `q` (Dvorak) to `move-end-of-line`. I tried adding this to my init file:

```
(define-key xah-fly-key-map (kbd "a") 'move-beginning-of-line)
```

And, as in "Xah Fly Keys Customization" documentation:

```
(setq my-nice-keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key my-nice-keymap (kbd "a") 'move-beginning-of-line)
```

But none of this worked for me, `a` in command mode stills gives me the same as `M-x`. Any suggestion?

Comment: The command to check a keybinding is M-x describe-key.  What does that say?

Comment: For 'a' it gives me: a runs the command execute-extended-command (found in
xah-fly-key-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

Comment: For 'q' (qwerty) it gives me: q runs the command xah-reformat-lines (found in xah-fly-key-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘xah-fly-keys.el’.